# Migrating Azure Ubuntu VM to vSphere - no networking after migration

Tags: networking, azure

I'm having a little trouble getting a VM connect to a network which was previously migrated away from Azure to vSphere. dmesg doesn't show any trace of an eth0 interface. Could this be related to the Azure-specific kernel that those Azure Marketplace VMs install as a default?
Which steps could I take to re-enable networking?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Linux kernel does not contain vmxnet3 module.
Need to change network adapter in VM settings to e1000 and use the following commands to activate network:

```
sudo modprobe e1000

sudo dhclient ens33
```